# Python not working when using pass in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop

I am making simple program that adds a piece of text to every file in the folder
however this code is also adding text to my python file so I made a if statement that stops this from happening. But now the script does not work at all.

```
import os

def main():
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file == 'main.py' or 'Password.txt:
            pass
        else:
            with open(file, 'a') as file:
                try:
                    file.write("hello")
                    print("sucess")
                except:
                    print("error")

main()
```

I have no idea why this is not working.
Thank you very much.

I expected this script to add hello to the end of every file but it does nothing at all.
It worked before I added the if statement to stop it from adding hello the the python file.

Edit: When I get rid of the or statement the code works perfectly fine.
I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Your actual issue is that in the if statement you are checking if (file == 'main.py') or if ('Password.txt') which is always true. You need to make it "if file == 'main.py' or file == 'Password.txt'"

Comment: cooldude, it's more pythonic to have: if file in ['main.py', 'password.txt']:

Comment: `pass` simply means "do nothing". Better would be to use `if file != 'main.py' and file != 'Password.txt'` to go directly to the `with` statement, or use `if file == 'main.py' or file == 'Password.txt': continue` so that the `with` statement doesn't need to be embedded in an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

this setup works for me:

`main.py`

```py
import os

def main():
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file == 'main.py':
            pass
        else:
            with open(file, 'a') as file:
                try:
                    file.write("hello")
                    print("sucess")
                except:
                    print("error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`tree`

```bash
.
├── main.py
└── test.txt
```

`test.txt`

- empty file before running
- after:

```
hello
```

### from the terminal I'm running

```bash
python3 main.py
```